# AngularJS element ID loaded with ng-include not found in index.html?

Tags: angularjs

So the flow is I visit `/` then the script load main.html which include header.html then inject to ng-view in index.html

Here is the detail

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <title>Koupon - Index</title>
    <!-- meta info -->
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <meta name="keywords" content="Koupon HTML5 Template" />
    <meta name="description" content="Koupon - Premiun HTML5 Template for Coupons Website">
    <meta name="author" content="Dark Cyber" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Google fonts -->
    <!-- <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <!-- <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> -->
    <!-- Bootstrap styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boostrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/boostrap_responsive.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome styles (icons) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font_awesome.css">
    <!-- Main Template styles -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">

    <!-- IE 8 Fallback -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/ie.css" />
<![endif]-->

    <!-- Your custom styles (blank file) -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyles.css">

    <!-- Backend Style -->

    <!-- End Backend Style -->

</head>

<body ng-app="rentalkika">



<!-- //// START PAGE CONTENT -->

    <div ng-view>

   </div>

<!-- END PAGE CONTENT /// -->


    <!-- Scripts queries -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/boostrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/nivo_slider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/countdown.min.js"></script>



    <script src="js/magnific.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/tweet.min.js"></script>

     <!--   
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

    <script src="js/gmap3.min.js"></script>
    -->
    <script src="js/wilto_slider.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mediaelement.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/fitvids.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/mail.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
     <script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
     <script src="js/ng-file-upload-shim.js"></script>
     <script src="js/ng-file-upload.js"></script>
     <script src="js/app.js"></script>
     <script src="js/flexnav.min.js"></script>


    <!-- Custom scripts -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" >
    if($('#something').length){
        alert('something found');
        //I want to init plugin with #something here    
    }else{
        alert('something not found');    
    }
    </script>

    <!-- Backend JS -->

    <!-- End Backend JS -->

</body>

</html>
```

`app.js`

```
$routeProvider
.when('/', {
    templateUrl : 'pages/main.html',    
    title: "Home"
})
```

`main.html`

```
<div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>



<!-- TOP AREA -->
    <div class="top-area">
        <!-- START BOOTSTRAP CAROUSEL -->
        <div id="my-carousel" class="carousel slide">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="active item">
                    <img src="img/1200x480.png" alt="Image Alternative text" title="Old No7" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption countdown-caption">
                        <h3>Jack Daniels Huge Pack</h3>
                        <!-- COUNTDOWN -->
                        <div data-countdown="Aug 25, 2013 5:30:00" class="countdown"></div><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Save 70%</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/1200x480.png" alt="Image Alternative text" title="iPhone 5 iPad mini iPad 3" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption countdown-caption">
                        <h3>Apple Big Deal</h3>
                        <!-- COUNTDOWN -->
                        <div data-countdown="Aug 30, 2013 10:45:00" class="countdown"></div><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Save 50%</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/1200x480.png" alt="Image Alternative text" title="the best mode of transport here in maldives" />
                    <div class="carousel-caption countdown-caption">
                        <h3>Finshing in Maldives</h3>
                        <!-- COUNTDOWN -->
                        <div data-countdown="Sep 2, 2013 22:00:00" class="countdown"></div><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Save 30%</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="carousel-control left" href="#my-carousel" data-slide="prev"></a>
            <a class="carousel-control right" href="#my-carousel" data-slide="next"></a>
        </div>
        <!-- END BOOTSTRAP CAROUSEL -->
    </div>
    <!-- END TOP AREA -->


<div ng-include="'footer.html'"></div>
```

`header.html`

```
    <!-- //////////////////////////////////
//////////////MAIN HEADER///////////// 
////////////////////////////////////-->
<div id="something">
</div>

    <header class="main">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span2">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="img/logo-small.png" alt="logo" title="logo" class="logo">
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="span8">
                    <!-- MAIN NAVIGATION -->
                    <div class="flexnav-menu-button" id="flexnav-menu-button">Menu</div>
                    <nav>
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills flexnav" id="flexnav" data-breakpoint="800">
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Layanan</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#sewa_mobil">Sewa Mobil</a>
                                    </li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Shuttle</a>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#">Paket Wisata</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">xxx</a></li>                                        
                                            <li><a href="#">bbb</a></li>                                        
                                        </ul>                            
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="blog-sidebar-right.html">Blog</a>
                            </li>
                                 <li><a href="#">FAQ</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="#register_partner">Tertarik menjadi mitra kami?</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </nav>
                    <!-- END MAIN NAVIGATION -->
                </div>
                <div class="span2">
                    <!-- LOGIN REGISTER LINKS -->
                    <ul class="login-register" ng-controller="LoginController">

                        <li ng-hide="loggedIn"><a class="popup-text" href="#login-dialog" data-effect="mfp-move-from-top"><i class="icon-signin"></i>Sign in</a>
                        </li>
                        <li ng-show="loggedIn"><a href="#" ng-click="logout()"><i class="icon-signout"></i>Sign out</a>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#register"><i class="icon-edit"></i>Sign up</a>
                        </li>

                           <!-- LOGIN REGISTER LINKS CONTENT -->
    <div id="login-dialog" class="mfp-with-anim mfp-hide mfp-dialog clearfix">
        <i class="icon-signin dialog-icon"></i>
        <h3>Member Login</h3>
        <h5>Welcome back, friend. Login to get started</h5>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <form class="dialog-form" ng-submit="handleLogin()" >
                <label>Username</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="yourUsername" ng-model="login.username" class="span12">
                <label>Password</label>
                <input type="password" placeholder="My secret password" ng-model="login.password" class="span12">
                <label class="checkbox">
                    <input type="checkbox">Remember me
                </label>
                <div class="control-group error" ng-show="error">
                <span class="error help-block">
                    {{ error }}
                </span>
                </div>
                <input type="submit" value="Sign in" class="btn btn-primary">
                <button ng-click="FBLogin()" class="btn btn-primary">Login with Facebook</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <!--
        <ul class="dialog-alt-links">
            <li><a class="popup-text" href="#register-dialog" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out">Not member yet</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="popup-text" href="#password-recover-dialog" data-effect="mfp-zoom-out">Forgot password</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        -->
    </div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>



    <div id="password-recover-dialog" class="mfp-with-anim mfp-hide mfp-dialog clearfix">
        <i class="icon-retweet dialog-icon"></i>
        <h3>Password Recovery</h3>
        <h5>Fortgot your password? Don't worry we can deal with it</h5>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <form class="dialog-form">
                <label>E-mail</label>
                <input type="text" placeholder="email@domain.com" class="span12">
                <input type="submit" value="Request new password" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END LOGIN REGISTER LINKS CONTENT -->

    <!-- //////////////////////////////////
//////////////END MAIN HEADER////////// 
////////////////////////////////////-->
```

The above script will alert `something not found` but if I put `<div id="something"></div>` directly to index.html the script will alert `something found`

What I need is `<div id="something"></div>` in header.html then I init plugin with `#something` in index.html

Is something wrong with my structure or code?

Comment: Do you have any console error ? Can you post a screenshot ? Did you make a `config` to set your routes ?

Comment: no error in console, yes using config.

Comment: Please supply more code, I don't even know what you want.

Comment: show the entire html file as it is. it looks like you missed some html tag

Comment: @trichetriche updated :D

Comment: @AniruddhaDas updated :D

Comment: Well I see no JS code. So I guess the problem might come from your `:hover` CSS code.

Comment: Try to move out ng-include="'footer.html'" and other incuded file to index.html and see if its working, if works then might be your templete code is not $compiled to angular

Comment: @AniruddhaDas not working :(

Comment: @trichetriche the background is changing when hover but the dropdown doesn't appear :(

Comment: Check the `z-index` property of your dropdown then

Comment: @trichetriche  just updated with live link and repo. hope you can help me.

Comment: @AniruddhaDas updated with live link and repo. hope you can help me.

Comment: finally found that element id in header.html not detected in index.html so how I can make it detect as I need #something in header.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="something" ng-controller="SomethingController">
</div>
```

then in your `SomethingController`

`$("#something").initPlugin();`